# How to add different type of child components to parent component on button click in reactJs application

Tags: reactjs, appendchild

I am new to reactjs, not getting how to add different type of child components on respective button click in menu bar to parent component.

Suppose there are child components representing arithmetic operation (PLUS, MINUS, Multiplication, Division) and Logic Operators(AND OR NOT XOR) and a parent component **OperationBuilder**

I want to add any combination arithmetic and logical operators or any other custom operators in parent component by clicking buttons available in menu bar and build a complex operation.

Basically i want to perform something similar to appendChild operation available in javascript in reactJs to add child component to parent component

Refer to following

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import Plus from "./Plus";
import Minus from "./Minus";
import And from "./And";`


function FunctionEditor() {


function AddPlusBlock() {
   const funEditor = document.getElementById('funEditor');
   // Add Plus Block to functionEditor
}

function addMinusBlock() {
    const funEditor = document.getElementById('funEditor');
    // Add Minus Block to functionEditor
}

function AddAndBlock() {
    let funEditor = document.getElementById('funEditor');
}


return (
    <div>
        <h5>Function Editor</h5>
        <span className='accordion-button'>
            <button className='btn border btn-group-sm' onClick=        
            {AddPlusBlock}>Plus</button>
            <button className='btn border btn-group-sm' onClick=
            {AddMinusBlock}>Minus</button>
            <button className='btn border btn-group-sm' onClick=
            {AddAndBlock}>And</button>
        </span>
          <div id="funEditor"></div>
    </div>);
  }

  export default FunctionEditor;
```

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: React uses state. Make a state array that your buttons can modify. Then render the UI based on that array.

Comment: @super : thank you for you response, can state array hold heterogeneous objects

Comment: It's javascript, so it's a normal javascript array.

Comment: Let me try that.